# import A java Library into groovy script [SoapUI]

Tags: java, xml, groovy, soapui

I developed a small java library to validate XML files, so I have to call it from SOAPUI using a groovy script
So how to import this library into my script and instantiate my class ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the jar file into the bin/ext directory.
Then in a groovy step, you can import your class and use it.